# Create several form in a same module or function in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, hooks

I want to create several forms from the same page. And these form I am generating from a custom module. I have already generated the function my_module_form (), but I can only create a single form. How can I generate more forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing limiting you to a single form, your page callback just needs to return a render array containing all of the ones you need:

```
return [
  'form_1' => drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form_1'),
  'form_2' => drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form_2')
  'form_3' => drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form_3'),
];
```